# What happens to male turkeys?

Tags: zoology, ecology, ornithology, population-biology

My family and I have almost never seen a wild male turkey though we have seen countless female turkeys. Is the male to female sex ratio of turkeys at birth extremely low? If not, what happens to the male turkeys?

Comment: Where do you live? I assume you are talking about wild turkeys? How did you distinguish between male & females?

Comment: This is referring to wild turkeys and in the western U.S. The main way is that the male turkeys have the big tail feathers in the back. Though I admit that it is possible that I am unable to distinguish between male and female turkeys otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

This article from the humane society suggests that the male-female ratio in wild turkeys is generally 1:1 [1](https://www.humanesociety.org/sites/default/files/docs/about-turkeys.pdf).

It's likely that nothing 'happens' to the male turkeys. Possibly you and your family may be miscounting some males as females; you mention in your comment the big tail feathers, but both sexes have fairly long tail feathers so that may not always be particularly reliable. The best way to tell the sexes apart are listed in this article [2](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Wild_Turkey/id) with pictures of both sexs and descriptions of what differences are most helpful for IDing. Younger male turkeys may also be more difficult to differentiate from females.

An additional point is that male and female turkeys [often form their own flocks](https://blog.nature.org/science/2017/11/21/the-fascinating-fall-behavior-of-wild-turkeys/). These flocks interact in certain times of year, but not all the time. Depending on the consistency of the timing and location of where you're seeing the turkeys, the high degree of females might just be due to this phenomenon. The places you're frequenting might be a popular hangout for a specific hen/chick flock, or several, leading you to conclude that there are way more female turkeys than males.